# Timer and Leaderboard

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hey guys I've been following the sudoku tutorial in hello android 3 and I'm wanting to extend on it by making a leaderboard where you can save high scores with a timer, so the quicker you do a puzzle the higer up on the board you are but I don't have a clue where to start, any suggestions or tutorial help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the Skiller SDK. I am using it for the game I am working on right now.
It's built with game devs in mind - and things like leaderboard and other goodies are just part of the SDK.
When you download the SDK you also get sample code for a working game - if you like learning by example.